# SharePoint 2013 REST display lookup fields?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, odata

I am using SharePoint 2013 REST to show data from my list,

one of my field in announce list is AnnouncedBy which is a user packer field

or is a lookup field

how can I display it or get it using SharePoint 2013 REST?

```
 var app = angular.module('SmartphoneOSList', ['ngSanitize']);  
 app.controller('ListController', function ($scope, $http) {  
 $http({  
    method: 'GET',  
    url: "https://myserver/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('announce')/items?$top=2&$orderby=Modified desc",  
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }  
   }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
     $scope.items = data.d.results;  

   }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
    //...
    });  
});
```

Comment: where you able to fix this issue?. My lookup output is in json

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to select `User` or `Lookup` field values the $expand operator is used (for making a projection of `AnnouncedBy` column with `User Information List`).

For example, the following query

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/news/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Announcements')/items?$select=*,AnnouncedBy/Title&$expand=AnnouncedBy
```

will return the following result:

[image]

**Complete example**

The example demonstrates how to bind User field value in AngularJs:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script> 
var app = angular.module('AnnouncementsList', ['ngSanitize']);  
app.controller('ListController', function ($scope, $http) {  
    $http({  
        method: 'GET',  
        url: "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Announcements')/items?$select=*,AnnouncedBy/Title&$expand=AnnouncedBy",  
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }  
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
        $scope.items = data.d.results;  
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
        //error handling goes here..
    });  
});  
</script>  


<h1>Announcements</h1>  
<div ng-app="AnnouncementsList">  
    <ul ng-controller="ListController">   
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">  
            <span>{{item.Title}}</span> By <span>{{item.AnnouncedBy.Title}}</span>  
        </li>  
    </ul>  
</div>
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: +1 for AngularJs :)

Comment: Yes the questioner was still confused, thanks for the details :)

Comment: @VadimGremyachev But if I expand the field and see the results, lookup field title is coming as null and id is coming as properly.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding following in the URL

```
$select=AnnouncedBy/Id,AnnouncedBy/Title,*&$expand=AnnouncedBy
```

Reference:

[SharePoint 2013–retrieving the lookup value of User fields using the REST API](http://www.sharepointalex.co.uk/index.php/2012/12/sharepoint-2013retrieving-the-lookup-value-of-user-fields-using-the-rest-api/)

[Getting User Information with the SharePoint 2013 REST API](http://sympmarc.com/2014/01/21/getting-user-information-with-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api/)

Comment: I had seen those posts but they are totally not constructive and not working

Comment: When I add your code: it looks like blow: 

 ABC   -   2014-11-11T09:04:14Z 
EYXdsldj lalsdfljalsjf​

{"__metadata":{"id":"b164b165-425d-418c-9629-e8900d0507f5","type":"SP.Data.UserInfoItem"},"Id":10,"Title":"Shofiqul Islam"}
Readmore...

Comment: `Shofiqul Islam` this is the user name right ?

Comment: Yes that is username

Comment: You can find how to access these in the given links. What else are you looking for?

Comment: How to display the name Just: Shafiqul Islam